# How to capture ubuntu to an installable iso

Tags: iso, oem

I want to deploy ubuntu to multiple computers with custom preinstalled apps and packages. I have customised an OEM installation (on a VM) but how do I capture it to a bootable image/installer.

Like in windows, after sysprep, you can capture the install.wim file with windows pe live boot and then make a custom iso.

Comment: See if this works for you. It uses an .IMG file not an .ISO file. https://askubuntu.com/q/1300540/43926

Comment: You should be able to create an image of the installed system and then clone it to another computer using Clonezilla: https://clonezilla.org/ . However, this is not "customized installation", this is just cloning of the installed system from one computer to another.

Answer (score 2):

1. without any especial tools you can [make filesystem.squashfs from Ubuntu root partition](https://askubuntu.com/a/1474413/1698042) as a backup so you can restore your Ubuntu and you can make Ubuntu [live USB by this file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1474717/create-usb-drive-contains-multi-ubuntu-versions-hbcd-pe-64-and-multi-windows-in) to install your ubuntu on another pc.
2. with [cubic](https://github.com/PJ-Singh-001/Cubic) you can customize your Ubuntu iso and get your iso file which can used to make live USB