How to backup the system including my configuration?
I would like to backup my current running system to a bootable USB as follows. My goal is to use the USB backup to restore my system to its state at the time of backup if necessary.
I don't need to include my data files in it because I can back them up in a different way, but what interests me most to include in the backup are the program customization or configuration files, including programs that I installed in addition to what comes with a standard installation.
EDIT: My recent experience is with MX Linux where that OS has a program called snapshot that takes backups and these may then be burned to a bootable USB using another one of their programs.
However, I looked into the matter a bit more and based on what I read I could probably follow the following approach. I'll use the System Backup program and keep the backups externally on a USB stick or an external drive. Under one scenario I would simply restore from one of the saved backups. Under another scenario where I cannot access my installation, I would use a Live CD-DVD to re-install the OS and then restore a backup from one of my saved backups.

see this answer https://askubuntu.com/a/1476122/1698042

This question is similar to: Create USB drive contains multi Ubuntu versions, HBCD-PE-64 and multi Windows installation. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

an alternative is to use Timeshift This ItsFOSS article explains how.

I edited my original posting to suggest what might be a solution to what I'm looking for. I would like something more user-friendly as a solution than what has been proposed. so far.

I'm familiar with Timeshift. I'll be using Timeshift as a backup to my backup solution!

This question is similar to: How can I make timeshift take a backup of the whole system?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

As pointed out by others, Timeshift is not suitable for document backups. It's appropriate for system backups.
